# Kana in Movie Title: 「シン・ゴジラ」

Tags: katakana

In the 2016 film, "Shin Godzilla", the Japanese title is rendered "シン・ゴジラ" (*shin gojira*).

I assume that this "shin" here is 神?

Why did they spell "shin" in katakana as if it was a foreign word? Thank you.

Comment: `“新、真、神…”見る人にさまざまなことを感じてもらいたいということで、正解があるわけではありません` -- https://www.news-postseven.com/archives/20160902_444204.html

Comment: See [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B4%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A9#%E8%A3%BD%E4%BD%9C). `...題名に「新」「真」「神」等、複数の意味を含ませた作名「シン・ゴジラ」と命名した。`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot read the Japanese wikipedia article. Would you be able to translate some of the pertinent material for me? Thank you.

Comment: *Gojira?* Hahaha... that sounds like one of those "funny" words (e.g. sausage, cow, butter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this news site](http://news.livedoor.com/article/detail/11967162/), the reason seems to be:

> 「シン・ゴジラ」の「シン」について山内章弘プロデューサーが語った
>   庵野秀明総監督のアイデアで「正解があるわけではありません」と回答
>   「新、真、神…見る人にさまざまなことを感じてもらいたい」とした

My literal TL of that would be:

> "Producer Akihiro Yamauchi talked about the 「シン」 part of 「シン・ゴジラ」.  He stated 'There is no correct answer to it.' and that was the intention of Director Hideaki Anno.  Yamauchi stated "We want the viewers to feel various things (in the title), such as 新 (new)、真 (true/real)、神 (god), etc."

(新, 真 and 神 can all be read 「しん」.)

Comment: This is a nice demonstration that homophones don't always cause trouble but can also make your writing more expressive.